# I have trouble with Message Filter Extension about extracting time or state of message handled

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, extension-methods, imessagefilter

I'm building an app that has Message Filter Extension. And I need to know what message was filtered. But I don't have permission to write in share groups. What I need to know just time and state of message. I have tried so many ways but they did't work .